# Typeahead TypeError: it.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-3

Good day. Please take a look at my scrit first.

My JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#outlet").typeahead({
         source: function(query, process) {

                $.ajax({
                 url: '<?=base_url();?>graph/outletlists',
                 data: {outlets:$("#outlet").val()},
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'JSON',
                 success: function(data) {
                          process(data);
                          console.log(data);
                        }               
                    });
         },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

My Controller

```
function outletlists()
    {
        extract(populateform());
        $hasil = $this->modelmodel->showdata("SELECT Outlet from transaksi where outlet like '%".$outlets."%' group by Outlet");
        echo json_encode($hasil);
    }
```

and my form

```
 <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Outlet</label>
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                   <input type="search" id="outlet" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." data-provide="typeahead" />
              </div>
   </div>
```

so, I'm using [Bootstrap3-typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead). From my script above i got this error

from `console.log(data)` i already have my desired result. So my problems are i can't see any suggestion and then i got this error from `firebug`

```
return ~it.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase());
```

This is what i got when i input `AR`

```
[{"Outlet":"K-AR3"},{"Outlet":"K-AR4"},{"Outlet":"K-ARN2"},{"Outlet":"K-ARN3"}]
```

any help would be appreciated, sorry for my bad english.

I try it to make it like the example at http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

```
var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#outlet").typeahead({
        autoSelect: true,
        minLength: 2,
        delay: 400,
        source: states
    });
});
```

and it works .

Results from `firebug`

> POST http://localhost:84/new_store/graph/outletlists   200 OK         375ms
>   jquery-....min.js (line 4) HeadersPostResponseHTMLCookies
>
> [{"Outlet":"K-AR3"},{"Outlet":"K-AR4"},{"Outlet":"K-ARN2"},{"Outlet":"K-ARN3"}]
>
> TypeError: b.toLowerCase is not a function
>
> ...on(a){var
>   b=this.displayText(a);return~b.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowe...
>
> bootstr....min.js (line 1, col 2903

I try to change my `bootstrap3-typeahead.js` to `bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js` end my error become like this

> TypeError: b.toLowerCase is not a function ...on(a){var
>   b=this.displayText(a);return~b.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowe...

Comment: what is '~it' here?

Comment: i don't know. It showing up from firebug

Comment: print / console log your '~it' first then apply toLowerCase(), debug it step by step

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as what i can see from your `console.log()`. you get this.

```
[{"Outlet":"K-AR3"},{"Outlet":"K-AR4"},{"Outlet":"K-ARN2"},{"Outlet":"K-ARN3"}]
```

you only need

```
[{"K-AR3"},{"K-AR4"},{"K-ARN2"},{"K-ARN3"}]
```

so try to change your controller to

```
function outletlists()
    {
        extract(populateform());
        $hasil = $this->modelmodel->showdata("SELECT Outlet from transaksi where outlet like '%".$outlets."%'  group by Outlet");
        $data = array();
        foreach ($hasil as $hsl)
            {
                $data[] = $hsl->Outlet;
            }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Comment: Just to close the loop on this you can also use something similar to this: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/issues/170 where you only select the value from the JSON key-pair that was returned.... item.value or in the example above item.outlet if you do no want to modify the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Even though there's been an accepted answer I'm going to offer another answer, as this one did not apply to my situation. It turned out that one of my array elements was a null value. So I rewrote my data query to filter out nulls.

Answer (score 0):

try to use following example as static code and then make it dynamic 
Example: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/.

Comment: that is great news